# Strict inequality in CSS media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Say I have this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    nav {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

This means undefined behaviour for a width like 600.5, which is a possible logical width on HiDPI diplays. The problem with `min-width`, `max-width`, etc are that they are weak inequalities (>= and <= respectively). How do I achieve strict inequality in CSS media queries (> and <)?

Comment: Please be nice to new users and don't downvote legit questions. I was able to achieve decimal widths. I always thought that it's rounded to an integer till I actually faced this problem. Here's proof: https://prnt.sc/iaahwp

Comment: Thank you for this great question. It's questions about extreme edge cases like this that should be most welcome here in SO, yet such questions used to be met with extreme hostility. I experienced the same in the past. I hope things will be different in the future.

Comment: Have you tried `min-width: 600.1px` or `min-width: 600.01px` instead? I wonder if that would work. I can't test here since the bounding rectangle width is always an integer for me.

Answer (score 1):

The width of the document will always be rounded to **an integer in `px`**. If you're interested in details, you can read [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20110309203035/https://elasticss.com/determination-of-algorithms-used-for-percentage-based-rounding-divs-on-browsers-and-css-frameworks/).

Let's make a simple test:

```js
// set width to 600.5px:
document.querySelector('body').style.width = '600.5px';

// get actual width:
console.log('600.5px gets parsed to ' + document.querySelector('body').offsetWidth);

// set width to 600.4999px:
document.querySelector('body').style.width = '600.4999px';

// get actual width
console.log('600.4999px gets parsed to ' + document.querySelector('body').offsetWidth);
```

This technically means `@media (max-width:600px)` applies when document width is equal or below `600.49994(9)px`. In practice, it never has decimal width.

Comment: Are you sure about this? This is a real problem I faced a few days ago when I had a mobile navbar set to display: none for width >= 601 and desktop navbar set to display: none for width <= 600, and I was clearly able to see both navbars on my screen if I resized the window just right. I typed this in the console: https://prnt.sc/iaahwp

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't read [this note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth). I'm unable to set the width of document to a value that displays both divs when the `width` is set in between. However, it looks like the CSS breakpoint is on `0`, not on `0.5`, as I originally thought. I'll update my answer once I make more tests, read more docs - to understand why it acts like this.

Comment: I found this article http://damienclarke.me/code/posts/those-1px-gaps-between-media-queries-can-be-a-problem. It seems having non-100% zooms can trigger this as well. It's up to the browser whether or not to round the viewport width when calculating media queries. `getBoundingClientRect().width` is the raw width which can have decimal places (which is probably what the browser is using for calculating media queries), whereas looks like from the link you mentioned, `clientWidth` gives the integer-rounded version of it

Comment: So as that article suggested, the best way to solve this would be to use only `min-width` or only `max-width` and set one of them `display: none` by default, and in the one media query switch them up. It's a shame there's no clear and easy way to do this with the help of strict inequalities

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve strict inequality using negation and nested media queries:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { display: none; }
}
@media only screen {
    @media not all and (max-width: 600px) {
        nav { display: block; }
    }
}
```

[Support seems excellent.](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_media_nested-queries) But it won't work on IE.

Another technique is to have a separate stylesheet. This is the only way on IE:

```html
<style media="screen">
@media not screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { display: block; }
}
</style>
```

Of course, if you don't care about other media types you could just put this in the original stylesheet. It will apply to screen above `max-width`, and to all other types regardless of width.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { display: none; }
}
@media not screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { display: block; }
}
```

But in the real world, we need to at least care about the print output, closely followed by accessibility (speech) and other media types. That's why we need to limit this to screen only using one of the two techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I've got some amazing news for you, reader, who arrive here in dispair: with [Media Queries Level 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#syntax_improvements_in_level_4), it is now possible to use `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` operators.

So the original question code can now be rewritten as follow:

```css
@media only screen and (width < 600px) {
    nav {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (width >= 600px) {
    nav {
        display: block;
    }
}
```